# Query many-to-many with results as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been asked to do a query but this is the first time they asked me this kind of query. Additionally, I didn't know how to name this question's title so I would like to apologize in case it might be misleading.

So, first of all I have two tables named Article and Attribute with a relationship of many-to-many. Each one of these has the following structure (with the most important columns), with some examples:

```
Article Table                                Attribute Table
--------------                 -----------------------------------------
| Article_id |                 |Attribute_id| Attribute_Name| Data_type|
|  Article1  |                 |      1     | Article_name  |   Text   |
|  Article2  |                 |      2     |    Height     |   Number |
|  Article3  |                 |      3     |  Description  |  Fulltext|
--------------                 -----------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the Article table contains only the article ID, while the rest of its attributes, such as its name or description, is found on the Attribute table. 
Also, not all Articles should have all the attributes. And last but not least, there are TONS of articles and tons of attributes (over 30), but I just put few ones as examples.

Now, the Article_Attribute table is kind of messy, because it has been made many years ago. It has this structure with some examples:

```
                          Article_Attribute table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Article_ID | Attribute_ID | Number_Value | Text_Value | Fulltext_Value |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Article1  |   Attribute1 |     NULL     | Tennis Ball|       NULL     |
|  Article1  |   Attribute3 |     NULL     |    NULL    |   Just a ball  |
|  Article2  |   Attribute1 |     NULL     |   Eraser   |       NULL     |
|  Article2  |   Attribute3 |     NULL     |    NULL    |  Paper eraser  |
|  Article3  |   Attribute1 |     13       |    NULL    |       NULL     |
|  Article3  |   Attribute2 |     NULL     |    Pencil  |       NULL     |
|  Article3  |   Attribute3 |     NULL     |    NULL    | A simple pencil|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it contains three columns for each Attribute's data_type instead of one single value column.

And now I need a query to obtain a result like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Article_ID | Article_Name |Article_Height|    Article_Description      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Article1  |  Tennis Ball |     NULL     |         Just a ball         |
|  Article2  |    Eraser    |     NULL     |         Paper eraser        |
|  Article3  |    Pencil    |      13      |       A simple pencil       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far so long I have this simple query:

```
select a.article_id, attr.attribute_name, ae.number_value, ae.text_value, ae.fulltext_value 
    FROM article as a 
    LEFT JOIN article_attribute as ae ON a.article_id = ae.article_id 
    LEFT JOIN attribute as attr ON ae.attribute_id = attr.id 
ORDER BY a.article_id ASC
```

Which gives me something..

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Article_ID | Attribute_name | Number_Value | Text_Value | Fulltext_Value |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Article1  |  Article_name  |     NULL     | Tennis Ball|     NULL       |
|  Article1  |   Description  |     NULL     |    NULL    |   Just a ball  |
|  Article2  |   Article_name |     NULL     |   Eraser   |       NULL     |
|  Article2  |   Description  |     NULL     |    NULL    |  Paper eraser  |
|  Article3  |   Article_name |     13       |    NULL    |       NULL     |
|  Article3  |     Height     |     NULL     |    Pencil  |       NULL     |
|  Article3  |   Description  |     NULL     |    NULL    | A simple pencil|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is basically as far I can go, since I'm not good on queries..

How should I do it? Should I use a stored procedure? How do I put the attribute names as columns?

Any help is really appreciated and I would like to thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: 
I didn't notice one big detail on the Attribute table: there are some attributes that actually have other tables as Data_type (oh god..). For instance, there's the color attribute:

```
              Attribute Table
------------------------------------------
|Attribute_id| Attribute_Name| Data_type |
|      1     | Article_name  |   Text    |
|      2     |    Height     |   Number  |
|      3     |  Description  |  Fulltext |
|      4     |     Color     |Color_Table|
------------------------------------------
```

And on this table, we just find the color_id and its name, like:

```
        Color Table
------------------------------
|      ID    |      Name     |
|      1     |      White    |
|      2     |      Black    |
------------------------------
```

On the article_attribute table, you find the value of the relationship on the Number_value column.

Is it still possible to do? There are 6 attributes that actually link to other tables. If this is impossible to do because this DB is really messed up and has been made many years ago, then it's ok, I will still appreciate and accept your answer.

Comment: I would make separate Article_Attribute tables for each data type... but anyway, does MAX() help at all?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you're trying to perform is known as a "pivot".

Whilst some other RDBMS natively provide useful syntax for effecting such operations, MySQL does not—its developers feel that such data manipulation is purely presentational and therefore better suited to a higher layer of your application code, rather than being something with which the database should be burdened.

If you *absolutely must* perform the pivot in MySQL then the only way to accomplish it in a truly dynamic fashion (i.e. without using any foreknowledge of the attributes or their data types) is by utilising "dynamic SQL"—i.e. where your final DML statement is assembled dynamically from the result of earlier operations.  The final statement we wish to execute will look something like this:

```
SELECT   aa.Article_ID,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(
           a.Attribute_Name = 'Name', 
           aa.Text_Value,
           NULL
         )) AS Article_Name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(
           a.Attribute_Name = 'Height', 
           aa.Number_Value,
           NULL
         )) AS Article_Height,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(
           a.Attribute_Name = 'Description', 
           aa.Fulltext_Value,
           NULL
         )) AS Article_Description
FROM     Article_Attribute aa JOIN Attribute a USING (Attribute_ID)
GROUP BY aa.Article_ID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a251d/1/0).

Can you see what's happening?  We're *grouping* the `Article_Attribute` table by article, then using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine the results of [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) operations that return `NULL` for all but the desired records.

We can dynamically generate such a statement from the contents of the `Attribute` table in any language of our choosing, and you'll probably find it easiest (and most understandable) to do so in your application code.

It happens that SQL itself also provides [the facility for generating and utilising dynamic statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and since you've not indicated what language your application is developed in, I've shown below how to do exactly that:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; -- to overcome default 1KB limitation

SELECT CONCAT('
  SELECT   aa.Article_ID, ', GROUP_CONCAT('
             GROUP_CONCAT(IF(
               a.Attribute_Name = ', QUOTE(Attribute_Name), ', 
               aa.`', REPLACE(Data_type, '`', '``'), '_Value`,
               NULL
             )) AS `Article_', REPLACE(Attribute_Name, '`', '``'), '`
           ' SEPARATOR ','), '
  FROM     Article_Attribute aa JOIN Attribute a USING (Attribute_ID)
  GROUP BY aa.Article_ID
') INTO @sql FROM Attribute;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a251d/2/2).

Hopefully you can see how the final statement is built from the `Attribute` table (it's the string, highlighted in red) and are able to port to whatever language you like.  I've quoted and used [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to escape any literal quote characters that happen to appear within the names of attributes or data types.

Comment: Unluckily I have found an inconvenient that I didn't notice on the Attribute table: some of them relates to other tables. I have added the details on the question, if it's not much an annoyance. Nevertheless, your answer is complete so I will still accept it.

Comment: @Jayve: Of course, it's *possible* to handle such cases—but you'll need to find some way of expressing the logic for determining whether a datatype references a further table or not.  One such way might be to inspect whether the `Data_type` matches the name of an existing table in the database; another might be to see if it has the suffix `_Table`; there may be other ways, depending on your business logic.  Overall, I'd comment that the database design does not exactly lend itself well to long-term maintainability or performant/sargable queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following gives the required result based on the data you provided:

```
SELECT a1.ArticleID,MAX(Text_Value) AS Article_Name, MAX(Number_Value) AS Article_Height, MAX(Fulltext_Value) AS Article_Description
FROM Article_Attribute a1
GROUP BY ArticleID
;
```

I am a little suspicious of using MAX here as it only works because NULL is always lower than not null. I would have preferred something like COALESCE but that is not an aggregate function so gives unreliable results with the GROUP BY.

Comment: This assumes that each Attribute uses its own unique data column in `Article_Attribute`, which is unlikely to be the case given that the OP stated "*there are TONS of articles and tons of attributes (over 30), but I just put few ones as examples*".

Comment: From the example data this appears to be the case (Article + Attribute is distinct), eg if there were more than one Article1, Attribute1 (currently only "Tennis Ball") then how would you match this up with Article1, Attribute3 ("Just a Ball") ? IE if we had another Article1, Attribute1 of "Angry Squirrel" There would be no way of knowing if either "Tennis Ball" or "Angry Squirrel" went with "Just a Ball".

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point.  Consider if there was a further Attribute, perhaps named `Width`, that had `Data_type='Number'` (same as for the `Height` attribute).  Now your approach of obtaining attribute values with `MAX(Number_value)` would yield the same value for both attributes irrespective of with which it's actually associated.